# Do I really need a [NC] in my RewriteRules?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, url-rewriting

While working with Apache as a rewrite proxy I've seen both of the variants below and I was always wondering why some people put the NC flag at the end of the RewriteRule. Today I decided to stop wondering and ask all of you :-)

There's no comparison happening in the RewriteRule so - for my understanding - it's unnecessary to put a focus on the case of the strings. Am I right, or do you have something to learn for me?

**Variant #1:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example-(?:foo|bar|baz)\.(?:com|de|es|fr|it|us)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.target.com/path/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

**Variant #2:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example-(?:foo|bar|baz)\.(?:com|de|es|fr|it|us)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.target.com/path/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey, take a look at my answer!

Comment: Hi, I did but I wasn't aware of that you're waiting for a reaction from me. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.target.com/path/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.target.com/path/$1 [R=301,L]
```

makes no difference.

---

**Info:** The `NC` flag means Non-case.

---

But when you are using something like:

```
RewriteRule (.*\.(jpg|gif|png))$ http://images.example.com$1 [R=301,NC]
```

It matters!

When you use it without `NC`, `(.*\.(jpg|gif|png))$` will only match:

```
example.jpg
example.png
example.gif
```

But, when  you use it with `NC`, `(.*\.(jpg|gif|png))$` will also match :

```
example.JPG
example.jPG
example.Png
example.gIf
#etc....
```

Basically it will match the characters after `example` no matter if they are uppercase are lowercase.

Even the `RewriteCond` in your case, does not need `NC` if you are using Linux.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example-(?:foo|bar|baz)\.(?:com|de|es|fr|it|us)$ [NC]
```

Will not work well on Linux.

But, if you are using Windows, you will probably need to always use `NC` for `RewriteCond`.

But, in one case, where you are comparing `%{HTTP_HOST}` in Linux or Windows, you will always need to add the NC flag, probably. Because domains are not case-sensitive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.example\.com [NC]
```